# Reasons for Linux to exclude a disk from the RAID10 array (degrade it) except for physical failure

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I would like to understand the set of conditions on which Linux considers a drive really faulty, excludes it from array and considers RAID10 array degraded.

As I know, neither SMART self-check reports, nor any of the SMART values about relocated sectors, nor block parity problems (/sys/block/md0/md/mismatch_cnt > 0 or even >10.000) are considered a reason to exclude a disk from array.

What are these reasons (except for when the drive is physically uncapable to communicate of course)?

Answer (score 2):

In principle, both **block read and write error** can take a disk offline. However, specific behavior depends on the kernel used.

From the **RECOVERY** section of [md man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/md.4.html):

> If the md driver detects a write error on a device in a RAID1, RAID4,
>   RAID5, RAID6, or RAID10 array, it immediately disables that device
>   (marking it as faulty) and continues operation on the remaining
>   devices. If there are spare drives, the driver will start recreating
>   on one of the spare drives the data which was on that failed drive,
>   either by copying a working drive in a RAID1 configuration, or by
>   doing calculations with the parity block on RAID4, RAID5 or RAID6, or
>   by finding and copying originals for RAID10.
>
> In kernels prior to about 2.6.15, a read error would cause the same
>   effect as a write error. In later kernels, a read-error will instead
>   cause md to attempt a recovery by overwriting the bad block. i.e. it
>   will find the correct data from elsewhere, write it over the block
>   that failed, and then try to read it back again. If either the write
>   or the re-read fail, md will treat the error the same way that a write
>   error is treated, and will fail the whole device.

Be sure to read the **BAD BLOCK LIST** section also:

> From Linux 3.5 each device in an md array can store a list of known-
>   bad-blocks.  This list is 4K in size and usually positioned at the end
>   of the space between the superblock and the data.
>
> When a block cannot be read and cannot be repaired by writing data
>   recovered from other devices, the address of the block is stored in
>   the bad block list.  Similarly if an attempt to write a block fails,
>   the address will be recorded as a bad block.  If attempting to record
>   the bad block fails, the whole device will be marked faulty.
>
> Attempting to read from a known bad block will cause a read error.
>   Attempting to write to a known bad block will be ignored if any write
>   errors have been reported by the device.  If there have been no write
>   errors then the data will be written to the known bad block and if
>   that succeeds, the address will be removed from the list.
>
> This allows an array to fail more gracefully - a few blocks on
>   different devices can be faulty without taking the whole array out of
>   action.

Comment: Thanks! But don't these two quotes contradict each other? First says, that if read/write fails, the whole device goes faulty. The second says, that the list of bad blocks is stored on the drive. What is the purpose of the bad block list, if finding a single one marks the whole device as faulty?

Comment: The bad block lists is a feature introduced with newer (3.5+) kernels. Before that kernel version, the behavior is the one described in the first quote.

Comment: So, from 3.5 on, if read or write fails, array will not degrade, but will just recover information, mark block as a bad one and continue to operate normally, right? Is there a way to get information about bad blocks on RAID in 3.5 kernels?